# Deleting a line containing an object and the line that comes from above using REGEX in NOTEPAD++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following list:

```
"domain": "example1.com"
"type": "web"
"domain": "example2.com"
"type": "web"
"domain": "example3.com"
"type": "mobile"
"domain": "example4.com"
"type": "web"
```

I want to use regex to search for "type": "mobile" and mark the line above it: "domain": "example3.com"
Then in Gaza NOTEPAD++ I can perform replace on these two lines together:
"domain": "example3.com"
"type": "mobile".This will be the result:

```
"domain": "example1.com"
"type": "web"
"domain": "example2.com"
"type": "web"
"domain": "example4.com"
"type": "web"
```

I tried using the following regex but the \n doesn't work
`"domain:*".*\n"type": "web"`

Answer (score 1):

The `:` should be after the `"` and you want to match `mobile` instead of `type`

```
"domain":.*\R"type": "mobile"\R?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dmzcws/1)